# How to change the horizontal movement direction of the player in Unity2D?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a 2D game in Unity and I am using in FixedUpdate() function the Input.GetMouseButtonDown() method. I want my player to change the horizontal direction, so for this I have the below code.

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
             {
                 if(change == true)
                 {
                     rb.velocity = new Vector2(-12,rb.velocity.y);
                     change=!change;
                 }
                 else if(change == false)
                 {
                     change=!change;
                     rb.velocity = new Vector2(12,rb.velocity.y);
                 }
     }
```

At the beginning, first 3-6 clicks, works fine (one click change direction, another click the other direction) but afterwards I have to press 2 or 3 times to change the actual direction.

What should I do to increase the accuracy, quality of changing directions?

Thank you very much for your patience and attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unity Documentation states that you have to use GetMouseButtonDown() in the Update function.

You probably should create a global boolean to save the value and reset it in the FixedUpdate(). Something like this:

```
boolean MouseButtonDown=false;
void Update(){
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
MouseButtonDown=true;
}
}

void FixedUpdate(){
if (MouseButtonDown)
             {
                 if(change == true)
                 {
                     rb.velocity = new Vector2(-12,rb.velocity.y);
                     change=!change;
                 }
                 else if(change == false)
                 {
                     change=!change;
                     rb.velocity = new Vector2(12,rb.velocity.y);
                 }
     }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it will move to the left and right continuously, but I solve it by replacing FixedUpdate with just Update() function. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `FixedUpdate()` function runs after a fixed interval of time, if you click the mouse button at the time when `if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` is executing then your input is taken into account. The `Update()` function runs for every frame that is being displayed on the screen, if your fps (frame rate) is 60fps it means that the `Update()` function runs 60 times per second so there's a very low possibility that your input isn't recorded. Hope that answers why your code isn't working.

What you can do is:

```
bool btnPressed = false;
void Update(){

    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !btnPressed){
        btnPressed = true;
    }

}

void FixedUpdate(){

    if(btnPressed){

        if(change == true){
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-12,rb.velocity.y);
            change=!change;
        }
        else if(change == false){
            change=!change;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(12,rb.velocity.y);
        }

        btnPressed = false;
    }
}
```